# Looking for simple confirm (continue/cancel) with don't show again checkbox

Tags: javascript

I am looking for jquery function to replace the standard javascript confirm but which can take an input parameter cookie name which will be either created or deleted when the checkbox on the popup is checked or unchecked. Obviously it would need a parameters for the header (Please confirm), and the question to be asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/0x15b5an/2/

```
function fnOpenNormalDialog() {
    // Define the Dialog and its properties.
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Modal",
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        create: function (e, ui) {
            var pane = $(this).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-buttonpane")
            $("<label class='shut-up' ><input  type='checkbox'/> Stop asking!</label>").prependTo(pane)
        },
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(true);
            },
                "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(false);
            }
        }
    });
}

$('#btnOpenDialog').click(fnOpenNormalDialog);
$(document).on("change", ".shut-up input", function () {
    alert("shut up! " + this.checked)
})

function callback(value) {
    if (value) {
        alert("Confirmed");
    } else {
        alert("Rejected");
    }
}
```